# If $X$ a compact metric space and $Y$ Hausdorff and $f: X \to Y$ a continuous surjection, then $Y$ is also a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology

The problem is to show that if $X$ is a compact metric space and $Y$ a Hausdorff space and there exists a continuous surjection $f: X \to Y$, then $Y$ is also a compact metric space.

Compact follows from $X$ being compact and $f$ being continuous. I know that a regular second countable space is metrizable, and $Y$ is regular since a compact Hausdorff space is normal, hence regular. So I only have to show $Y$ has a countable basis.

I know $X$ has a countable basis and that $f$ is a closed map, so my idea was to let the basic elements in $Y$ be $V_i = Y - f(X - U_i)$ where $U_i$ is a basic element of $X$. But I keep getting inclusion in the wrong direction when I try to show these $V_i$ form a basis. I.e. if $y \in Y$ and $U \in Y$ is an open set containing $y$, then $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is closed and $f^{-1}(V)$ is open so $f^{-1}(V)$ is a union of basic open sets that cover $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. So there exists a finite subcovering. So I have $f^{-1}(y) \subset \cup_{i=1}^n U_i \subset f^{-1}(V)$, so $y \subset f(\cup_{i=1}^n U_i) \subset V$, but I can't show that $f(\cup_{i=1}^n U_i)$ is contained in any $V_i$. Am I headed in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Quibble: $Y$ is not a metric space, because no metric on it has been specified.  I think you mean $Y$ is a compact metrizable space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was noted in the comments, you actually mean that $Y$ is a compact *metrizable* space: a *metric* space requires a specific metric.

The usual argument is actually a bit more indirect than the one that you’re attempting to carry out; I’ll give you a map to follow and leave the details for you to work out.

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a base for $X$, and without loss of generality assume that $\mathscr{B}$ is closed under taking finite unions. Let $\mathscr{N}=\{f[B]:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$. The members of $\mathscr{N}$ need not be open, but in all other respects $\mathscr{N}$ behaves like a base for $Y$.

- Show that a set $U\subseteq Y$ is open iff for each $y\in U$ there is an $N\in\mathscr{N}$ such that $y\in N\subseteq U$. (You’ll need both the compactness of $X$ and the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is closed under taking finite unions.)

Such a family $\mathscr{N}$ is called a *network* for the space $Y$.

- Verify that $\mathscr{N}$ is closed under taking finite unions.
- Use the compactness and regularity of $Y$ to show that if $U$ is open in $Y$, and $y\in U$, then $y\in\operatorname{int}_YN\subseteq N\subseteq U$ for some $N\in\mathscr{N}$.
- Conclude that $\{\operatorname{int}_YN:N\in\mathscr{N}\}$ is a countable network of open sets and therefore is a countable base for $Y$.

---

In fact there is a general theorem:

> If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and $\mathscr{N}$ is a network for $X$, then $X$ has a base $\mathscr{B}$ such that $|\mathscr{B}|\le|\mathscr{N}|$.

Comment: The argument? Now I have to produce a better argument.

Comment: great answer!!! +1